# MUMIn pdredge error with glmer

Tags: r, lme4, inference, model-comparison

I'm trying to use the parallel computing version of dredge (package MUMIn) for model selection of my full glmer model:

```
 modmer.pom.full<-glmer(cbind(TEST,CONTROL)~ G+MS+l+MS*l+G*MS+G*l+I(l^2) + (1|c)+(1|s)+(1|l)+offset(log(qTEST/qCONTROL)),family=binomial(link = "logit"),data=df.pom.mer, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

after setting the R cluster to be run in parallel,

```
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterExport(cl,"df.pom.mer")
```

I simply tried to use the pdredge function as it follows:

```
pdredge(modmer.pom.full,cluster=cl,rank = "AIC")
```

but there is not evaluation, contrary, I got the following output for all submodels:

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  could not find function "glmer" (model 0 skipped)
```

I did not observed this problem by using the non-parallel computing  function dredge. It seems that glmer is not recognized by pdredge, but I could not find the cause. I'm new user of both MUMIn and parallel packages, so could it be that I' missing something importnat in pdredge arguments?

Thanks a lot, Juan

Comment: It is explained in `?pdredge` -> "Details" (first paragraph).

Comment: upppsss...thanks a lot Kamil and sorry for this; I should think twice before asking. Solved.

Comment: Hi - I found your post in Cross Validation - Use nonlinear mixed model for binomial distributed data.  I am trying to work on the same issue now and was wondering if you ever had any progress in the R environment  on this topic?  I just tried to use the nlme package  to estimate the 3 selectivity parameters using a mixed effect apporach, but am having issues with residuals probably because I am not accounting for the  log-likelihood binomial mass function.

Comment: Hi user41509. Sorry for this late response. Nothing new under the sun, I haven't found any reliable way to implement the paired gear structural model (I guess we are talking about the same approach !?) into a mixed model approach, what's about you currently?

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, as suggested in comments, this works fine if you *either* (1) specify the fully qualified name (`lme4::lmer` below) *or* (2) use `clusterEvalQ(cluster, library(lme4))` to make sure the package is loaded on the workers.

```
library(lme4)
library(parallel )
cluster = makeCluster(3, type = "SOCK")  ## also need snow installed
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(1000),x2=rnorm(1000),x3=rnorm(1000),f=rep(1:20,each=50))
dd$z <- simulate(~x1+x2+x3+(1|f), newdata=dd, 
      newparams=list(theta=1,beta=rep(1,4), sigma=1), family=gaussian)[[1]]
full_model = lme4::lmer(z ~ x1*x2*x3 + (1 | f), data = dd, 
                        REML = FALSE, na.action = "na.fail")
clusterExport(cluster,"dd")
clusterEvalQ(cluster, library(lme4))
MuMIn::pdredge(full_model, cluster)
```